# API-Gateway recipient validation of dynamically generated recipients

Tags: azure, api, email, gateway, office365connectors

new to community and new to IT. but been struggling with the topic for so long that decided to explore IT communities :)

We migrated 3rd party app to our corporate Azure Cloud. There is a feature in the app which allows to send calendar invites to our employees (corporate AD accounts).
The invites are sent by 3rd party from an app, so that the different calendar entries are shown in the web application and in fact the external sender generates dynamically recipient addresses each and every time (adds number in the end of the email). These recipient addresses are stored in our corporate Azure server DB.
There shall be recipient validation at the Gateway server, which fails cos the newly created accounts are not in our AD.. and we cannot just bulk upload "random" IDs to AD..

Bypassing recipients validation – is not possible, it is mandatory to have recipient validation
On the gateway it is prohibited to have exclusion for dynamic user validation

Gateway team suggested we can explore if we can "club dynamic users" and match them under "corporate user" (already in AD). Provider pushed back (ultimately they own an app)

AD team suggested we can explore and try to add any proxy email address - can be done either via on-prem exchange server (so that it is replicated in AD). The Mail team said not possible "Of course this is very tricky with static entries coming from AD  and the requirement of having recipient validation. In the end, if the App cannot map correct corporate addresses to the dynamic IDs, there's not much we can do from our side."...
here was the response from the provide:
"the app is generating new recipient addresses, because it makes it more convenient for the different stakeholders to add a specific e-mail address, instead of generating dynamic subjects.
In order for this feature to work, we simply need the possibility to receive e-mails from different domains."